# Create wordpress table, where am i going wrong?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

```
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "product_order";   

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            range VARCHAR(255),
            category VARCHAR(255),
            order mediumint(9),
            relation mediumint(9),
            UNIQUE KEY id (id)
        );";

        $wpdb->query($sql);
```

That doesn't seem to create a table... any reasons why? I tried dbdelta too.

Comment: Surround `range` and `order` by backticks. They are keywords.

Comment: Oh god thankyou. that's the one... put as answer and ill tick it :D

Comment: Those are both reserved words in MySQL - to prevent future issues it might be best to choose different column names, or start surrounding all your table names in back ticks.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-tables/screenshots/

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of an answer, surround the column names in back ticks as `range` and `order` are reserved words in MySQL:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `range` VARCHAR(255),
        `category` VARCHAR(255),
        `order` mediumint(9),
        `relation` mediumint(9),
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    );";
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

As a side note, if you want to make sure you don't conflict with other tables should this schema be shared with other wordpress instances or become a multisite, consider using `{$wpdb->prefix}$table_name` instead of just `$table_name` to use the database prefix defined in `wp-config.php`.